# Quiet import-module even when Verbosity is set

Tags: powershell, verbose, import-module

I want my custom write-verbose message to show, but do not want Import-Module to show any verbose messages

is there a flag I can use for Import-Module to keep it quiet, even though I have set $VerbosePreference = "continue"?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `-Verbose:$false`?

Comment: @MickyBalladelli - that should work.